# How to use gcloud with Babashka

Tags: clojure, gcloud, babashka

I'm trying to use Babashka to replace a few Bash scripts I use to deploy functions on GCP Cloud Functions.

The script below is working, but I wonder if there is a better way to execute the `gcloud` shell command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bb
(require '[cheshire.core :as json]
         '[clojure.java.shell :refer [sh]])

(let [package-json (json/parse-string (slurp "package.json") true)
      name (:name package-json)
      entry-point "entryPoint"
      region "europe-west3"
      memory "128MB"
      runtime "nodejs14"
      source "dist"
      service-account "sa-function-invoker@prj-kitchen-sink.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      timeout "10s"]
  (println "deploy function" name "with entry point" entry-point "to GCP Cloud Functions." "Attach service account" service-account)
  (let [output (sh "gcloud" "functions" "deploy" name "--region" region "--entry-point" entry-point "--memory" memory "--runtime" runtime "--service-account" service-account "--source" source "--trigger-http" "--timeout" timeout)]
    (if (= "" (:err output))
      (println (:out output))
      (println (:err output)))))
```

As a comparison, the Bash script I was using is easier to read:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

FUNCTION_NAME=$(cat package.json | jq '{name}' | jq '.name' | sed 's/"//g')
FUNCTION_ENTRY_POINT=entryPoint
ATTACHED_SA=sa-function-invoker@prj-kitchen-sink.iam.gserviceaccount.com
MEMORY=128MB

echo "deploy function `${FUNCTION_NAME}` with entry point `${FUNCTION_ENTRY_POINT}` to GCP Cloud Functions. Attach service account `${ATTACHED_SA}`"

gcloud functions deploy ${FUNCTION_NAME} \
  --project ${GCP_PROJECT_ID} \
  --region ${GCP_REGION} \
  --memory ${MEMORY} \
  --runtime nodejs14 \
  --service-account ${ATTACHED_SA} \
  --source dist \
  --entry-point ${FUNCTION_ENTRY_POINT} \
  --timeout 10s
```

I guess my question is not very specific to Babashka or gcloud, but it's about how to construct commands with clojure.java.shell in general...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute the shell command and see the direct output as it appears, I recommend using `babashka.process/process` or `babashka.tasks/shell`:

```clj
@(babashka.process/process ["ls" "-la"] {:out :inherit :err :inherit})

@(babashka.process/process ["ls" "-la"] {:inherit true})

(babashka.tasks/shell "ls -la")
```

The above invocations do pretty much the same, but `shell` also applied `babashka.process/check` which throws if the exit code was non-zero. The `@` sign before the invocation is the same as calling `deref` which means: wait for the process to finish. If you don't prepend that, than the process is going to run asynchronously.

More info:

- https://github.com/babashka/process
- https://book.babashka.org/#tasks

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the tip about `deref`. Omitting the `@` might be a good idea when executing gcloud commands that provision virtual machines or perform any other long-running operation.

Answer (score 1):

One trick I use to simplify calling out to the shell is shown by [this helper function](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/21.09.07/api/tupelo.misc#shell-cmd):

```
(shell-cmd cmd-str)
Runs a command string in the default OS shell (/bin/bash); returns result in a Clojure map. Example:

 (shell-cmd "ls -ldF *")
   ;=>   {:exit    0     ; unix exit status (0 -> normal)
          :err    ''     ; text from any errors
          :out    '...'  ; text output as would printed to console
         }
```

It allows you to write a single command string, instead of having to manually tokenize all the parts of the string.  The implementation is quite simple:

```
 (def ^:dynamic *os-shell* "/bin/bash") ; could also use /bin/zsh, etc

 (defn shell-cmd
   [cmd-str]
   (let [result (shell/sh *os-shell* "-c" cmd-str)]
     (if (= 0 (grab :exit result))
       result
       (throw (ex-info "shell-cmd: clojure.java.shell/sh failed, cmd-str:" (vals->map cmd-str result))))))
```

So it allows you to send a command string directly to `/bin/bash` and allow it to parse the args as normal.

I used this extensively a few years back to control AWS RDS hosts (creating, snapshots, selecting, deleting) via the AWS CLI and it was very easy to use.